# How to see all the minted nfts and the owner addresses during development?

Tags: nft, erc-1155

I am minting nfts using the 1155 ERC standard, and after they are minted, putting the contract address into metamask doesn't show the nfts in the wallet, which suggests that metamask doesn't support those tokens yet.
I'm deploying these contracts on ganache locally. Is there a way for me to list all the tokens and their respective addresses? Maybe there's a way this can be achieved with truffle?

Comment: It seems Metamask doesn't have the capacity of displaying NFT yet (https://metamask.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360058238591-NFT-tokens-in-your-MetaMask-wallet).

Answer (score 0):

Ok try deploying these smart contracts on a testnet such as rinkeby. Then mint the NFTs from a rinkeby network. Then download the metamask app in your phone. Import the rinkeby address on your metamask app. You will now be able to see the minted NFTs in the app